# what is typical car alternator inductance?

Tags: inductor

Anyone know the typical line-to-line inductance of a car alternator? I'm looking for a cheap stator to use as a 3-phase high-current inductor.

Comment: Do you have a spare alternator handy? It shouldn't be too hard to measure. Alternatively, if you have a portable LCR meter, I bet you could go to an auto-parts store, and ask to take a look at a new alternator, and measure it without having to pay.

Answer (score 2):

hmm, the only hint of an answer I found is in this paper: http://cdn.intechopen.com/pdfs/38166/InTech-Power_electronic_solutions_to_improve_the_performance_of_lundell_automotive_alternators.pdf; on p. 183 it says they looked at a Delcotron 22SI Type 12V-100A, and in its original configuration it is 0.1 ohm, 390uH, 6 pole pairs.